# Sql Scalar Variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue understanding scalar variables in SQL as the logic doesn't seem to compare with what I am used to in C.

Working on this stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_GetUserNameByLast4SSNandDOB]
    @SSN varchar(4)
    @DOB date
AS
    SELECT
        User_FirstName + ' ' + User_LastName AS EmployeeName 
    FROM
        tblUsers m 
    WHERE
        RIGHT(m.User_SSN, 4) = @SSN 
        AND m.User_DOB = @DOB
```

Trying to just pass in the variables and return the one row that will be returned. But it seems to always be that the variable is scalar. Any help with understanding how to avoid scalars is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Tag your questions with the database you are using.

Comment: you might want to think about the nature of the languages where SQL and C are two different systems.. where C is a programming language that mostly plays your application while SQL is a database language and database itself has its own structure... i don't see SQL being able to accommodate non-scalar variables as everything has to be defined here, i suppose every bit counts here

Comment: Side note for **SQL Server**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, is the procedure not Creating?

I can see one error:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_GetUserNameByLast4SSNandDOB]
@SSN varchar(4),
@DOB date
as
Select User_FirstName+' '+User_LastName as EmployeeName from tblUsers m 
where RIGHT(m.User_SSN,4)= @SSN and m.User_DOB= @DOB
```

Just note the , between the variables.

Comment: we all know the error... the main question is about scalar variables

Comment: Wow.  My error was as small as a comma.  I've been looking at this trying to figure out why the logic seemed sound but it wasn't working.

But yes.  Learning about how scalars function is something I've been trying to wrap my head around.

Comment: Unfortunately I am also in the dark still regarding scalar variables, just thought I pointed out the problem I noticed.